# How to find cyclic coordinates for a given Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

If you are given a Lagrangian in coordinates which are not cyclic, is there a rule for finding a transformation of the coordinates to another set of coordinates where one of them is cyclic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any specific 'rule' in regards to transformations to cyclic coordinates.

Given the Lagrangian in a specific set of coordinates, it may just be by inspection that you see that coordinates in another system become cyclic.

It also helps to know what system the Lagrangian is representing. For example, something rotating, cyclic coordinates might not be immediately obvious in Cartesian, but there is more than likely some cyclic coordinates in Polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The  Lagrangian $L=T-U$ is a function of the generalized coordinates $\vec{q}$ and $\vec{\dot{q}}$.  if you don't have applied forces :

then the criteria to find a cyclic coordinate is:

obtain the vector equation

$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}}\right)^T}_{\vec A}=
\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{q}}\right)^T}_{\vec B}\tag 1$$

for each $B_i$ component that equal zero,  $A_i$ is the cyclic coordinate

**Example I:**

$$L=\frac 12\,{h}^{2} \left( m{\dot\varphi }^{2}-m{\dot\varphi }^{2} \left( \cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}+{\dot\vartheta }^{2}\,m+ \left( 
\cos \left( \vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) 
$$

the generalized coordinates are:

$$\vec{q}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} \varphi \\ \vartheta 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

Thus equation (1)

$$ \underbrace{\left[ \begin {array}{c} {h}^{2}m\,\dot\varphi \, \left( \sin \left( 
\vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}\\  {h}^{2}\dot
\vartheta \,m\end {array} \right] 
}_{\vec{A}}=\underbrace{\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\  -{h}^{2}\cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \sin \left( \vartheta  \right)  \left( -m\,{\dot\varphi 
}^{2}+1 \right) \end {array} \right]}_{\vec B}
$$

$\Rightarrow$

the cyclic coordinate is
$${h}^{2}m\,\dot\varphi \, \left( \sin \left( 
\vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}=\text{constant}~,
\dot\varphi \, \left( \sin \left( 
\vartheta  \right)  \right) ^{2}=\text{constant}$$

**Example II:**

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\vec{\omega}^T\,I\,\vec{\omega}+\tau_\varphi\,\varphi$$

where $\tau_\varphi$ is applied torque.

with:

$$\vec{q}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} \varphi \\  \vartheta 
\\ \psi\end {array} \right]
$$

the inertial tensor $I$

$$I=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\it Ix}&0&0\\ 0&{\it Ix
}&0\\ 0&0&{\it Ix}\end {array} \right]
$$

and  the angular angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$

$$\vec\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \sin \left( 
\psi \right) \dot\varphi -\cos \left( \psi \right) \dot\vartheta 
\\  -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left( \psi
 \right) \dot\varphi +\sin \left( \psi \right) \dot\vartheta 
\\  \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\varphi +\dot\psi 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

Equation (1):

$$\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\it Ix}\, \left( \dot\varphi +\cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \dot\psi  \right) \\  {\it Ix}\,\dot
\vartheta \\   \left( \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) 
\dot\varphi +\dot\psi  \right) {\it Ix}\end {array} \right]
=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \tau \varphi \\  -{\it Ix}
\,\dot\varphi \,\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\psi 
\\  0\end {array} \right] 
$$

thus:

the cyclic coordinate is :

$$ \left( \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) 
\dot\varphi +\dot\psi  \right) =\text{constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

Something that can help is that you must first formulate the Lagrangian in the most convenient coordinate system, that is, according to its symmetry; Once the Lagrangian is built, look at which coordinate is not explicitly included in the Lagrangian; This coordinate will then be cyclical and its conjugate moment will be an integral of the dynamics of the system.
It is not the only method to find the cyclic coordinates but it helps.